# Trouble with Python: "TypeError: 'str' object not callable" when using round() function, value is a FLOAT variable

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python, and have just learned basic conditionals and logic operators. I am currently working on a project that takes the weight of a user and converts it to kg if it is in lbs, or lbs if it is in kg, depending on user input.

While I was testing out my program, the console spit an error:

[image: line 15, in < module > ; weight = round(conv) ; TypeError: 'str' object is not callable; Process finished with exit code 1;]

I double checked my code and I am rounding a variable that stores a float value. It is not a string, so I don't know why I got this error. I tried changing the variable name and reseting but those didn't help. Am I missing something painfully obvious here? I apologize if I am, I'm still very new to Python and to programing in general but would like to get good at it. Here is my source code:

```
import sys
un_weight = int((input("Weight: ")))
value = input("Is your weight in (L)bs or (K)g: ")

if (value == "K") or (value == "k"):
    conv = un_weight * 2.2
elif (value == "L") or (value == "l"):
    conv = un_weight / 2.2
else:
    print("That weight type does not exist. Please try again.")

round = input("Do you want your number rounded? (Y/N): ")

if (round == "Y") or (round == "y") or (round == "Yes") or (round == "yes"):
    print("Rounding Number... ")
    weight = round(conv)
    round_op = True
elif (round == "N") or (round == "n") or (round == "No") or (round == "no"):
    print("Rounding operation terminated. Calculating decimal weight...")
    round_op = False
else:
    print("That is not a valid answer. Please try again.")
    exit()

if (value == "K") or (value == "k") and not round_op:
    print(f"Your weight is {conv} Lbs.")
elif (value == "L") or (value == "l") and not round_op:
    print(f"Your weight is {conv} Kg.")
elif (value == "K") or (value == "k") and round_op:
    print(f"Your rounded weight is about {weight} Lbs.")
elif (value == "L") or (value == "l") and round_op:
    print(f"Your rounded weight is about {weight} Kg.")
else:
    print("Error: Operation failed. Please try again later.")
    exit()
```

As you can see, the `un_weight` variable is immediately converted into an integer with the `int()` function, so I don't know why Python thinks it is a string (if that even is what it's saying). Please excuse the dumb question; I would just like to know the reason behind this. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: On this line `round = input("Do you want your number rounded? (Y/N): ")` you create a variable that overrides the `round` function. Change your variable name and the function will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
round = input("Do you want your number rounded? (Y/N): ")
```

You've replaced the `round()` function with your variable that contains the input string.

Don't use variable names that are the same as built-in functions. There can only be one thing named `round` -- if it's your string, then it's not the mathematical function.